# PHP / Selenium : Uncaught Error: Class "Facebook\WebDriver\WebDriverActions" not found

Tags: php, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to simulate some human behaviour with PHP Selenium that requires WebDriverActions but I always get the same error message : Uncaught Error: Class "Facebook\WebDriver\WebDriverActions" not found

I have this at the beginning of my script:

```
use Facebook\WebDriver\Chrome\ChromeOptions;
use Facebook\WebDriver\WebDriverActions;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver;
use Facebook\WebDriver\WebDriverBy;
use Facebook\WebDriver\WebDriverExpectedCondition;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\DesiredCapabilities;
use Facebook\WebDriver\WebDriverWait;
```

My composer looks like this:

```
{
"require": {
    "grpc/grpc": "^1.57",
    "googleads/google-ads-php": "^21.1",

    "guzzle/parser": "^3.9",
    "google/apiclient": "2.15.0",
    "jovix/dataforseo-clientv3": "^1.1",
    "aliexpress/ae-sdk": "^1.2",
    "clchangnet/aliexapi": "^1.2",
    "symfony/dom-crawler": "^7.0",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.8",
    "symfony/css-selector": "^7.0",
    "psr/log": "^1.0",
    "chrome-php/chrome": "^1.10",
    "evenement/evenement": "^3.0.1",
    "chrome-php/wrench": "^1.5",
    "facebook/webdriver": "^1.7",
    "php-webdriver/webdriver": "^1.15"
},
"require-dev": {
    "symfony/panther": "^2.1",
    "dbrekelmans/bdi": "^1.1",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^11.0"
}
```

}

And in my code I'm using:

```
    $elementSize = $element->getSize();

    
    $randomX = rand(0, $elementSize->getWidth());
    $randomY = rand(0, $elementSize->getHeight());
    
    
    $actions = new WebDriverActions($driver); // the error is pointing here
    $actions->moveToElement($element, $randomX, $randomY)->perform();
```

I see that some other people have faced the same issue but no solution was posted here or on Github.

Chromedriver is running as a standalone server in the background.

Any idea?

Thanks